What does an ontic hidden variable quantum model achieve?
Is it only to show that maybe, preparations can be depicted in a form other than the density matrix and measurements other than POVMs? Or does it also introduce realism in the sense that all observables already have a fixed value (because of a hidden state of the preparation apparatus). If so how does it reconcile with non-commuting observables? Do we have to further assume subsequent hidden variables for every different observable?

An ontic hidden variable theory is what many people mean by “realism”; the idea that there is something there even if we’re not looking.
There are lots of reasons why physicists keep looking for such a realistic model of quantum phenomena; I’ll list some of them below.  But first, I’m going to push back on your phrase that this means “all observables already have a fixed value”.  Even apart from the crucial questions, “fixed by what?”, and “what do you mean by ‘already’?”, there is a widespread understanding that the act of measurement is an invasive process that could itself change the state of the system dramatically.  Also, the literal “observable” is the reading on the measurement device, not necessarily corresponding to the ontic state of the measured system.  In Bohmian mechanics, for example (a “realist”, hidden-variable theory), a measurement outcome for the momentum need not actually correspond to the ontic momentum of the measured particle.  So instead of thinking in terms of “observables”, an ontic hidden variable theory just means that there are some “be-ables” (as Bell called them) that can be taken to be the actual state of reality.  The essential idea is that we don’t know all of the beables, but they’re still “really there” all the same.
So: why consider ontic/realist viewpoints?  Some reasons:

Such a framework is arguably necessary to distinguish objective reality from subjective knowledge.  If one believes there is a difference between these two, and also thinks that there are certain aspects of quantum state or density matrices which are at least somewhat subjective, it makes sense to postulate some deeper level that isn’t subjective at all, a level that might correspond to reality as it really is.

It would explain the presence of probabilities in our fundamental theories.  In all classical situations, probability indicates there is something we don’t know.  Lots of people look to the probabilistic aspects of quantum theory to imply that there is something we don’t know there, too.  If there are hidden ontic beables, it would explain why our existing theory was probabilistic.

It would explain the (mathematical) collapse of the wavefunction in our present theory.  If there is something we don’t know, then the wavefunction becomes a state of knowledge, not a state of reality.  And when you learn something new, one updates their state of knowledge (essentially, Bayesian updating).  This would immediately explain why, whenever we learn something new, we see a strange discontinuous update to our wavefunctions.  This wouldn’t be entirely a real collapse, but (at least in part) it could be the sort of “update” you do when you see a friend across the street who you thought might be out of town.

If you go a bit further and imagine that at least some of the ontic hidden variables are not just beables, but “local beables” – associated with locations in space and time – you get a bunch of other benefits as well.  You start getting deeper explanations of why things look localized on macroscopic scales and why theories like general relativity (GR) might work in the first place.

If you go even further and consider theories with exclusively local beables, other things might fall into place as well.  It would explain why we use configuration spaces in quantum theory (for the same reason as in classical statistical mechanics, to keep track of correlations given some unknowns).  It would also offer a novel way to reconcile GR with quantum theory.  (Instead of “quantizing gravity”, one might imagine that the local beables could be directly incorporated into classical GR.). This starts to get into the well-known no-go-theorems, which puts serious constraints on how such beables would have to behave, but even then, all is not lost.  (Here are two very different resolutions:  Norsen, Wharton-Argaman.)

Finally, and more generally, this is how science works.  Many previous scientific advances were enabled by asking essentially these very same questions.  If 19th century physicists weren’t concerned with hidden variable theories, they would have been happy with the laws of thermodynamics as they were, and would never have bothered exploring the idea that hidden atoms and molecules might explain those laws from a deeper level.  If Faraday and Maxwell were only concerned with charges and currents, they never would have considered electric and magnetic fields as actually existing.  This is how fundamental progress is made; by trying to drill down to a deeper level to explain why certain theories seem to be so successful.  And despite some physicists actively discouraging others from exploring hidden variable models, or from even pondering quantum foundations at all, after 100 years it’s perhaps finally dawning on people that we can’t declare some theory as fundamental, just because we don’t yet know what’s going on at the next level down.


Hope that helps make more sense of why hidden variable models are still widely considered and explored in a quantum context.
